# Adding variables to char *

Tags: mysql, c, char

I would like to change the values in my `char *` to the int and double that are declared so I can change them without touching char *sql.
(on ubuntu using C)

How can i do this?

code:

```
int sensor_id = 10;

double temp = 22.22;

char *sql = "INSERT INTO test_table(sensor_id, sensor_value) VALUES(10, 22.22)";
```

Comment: What platform? For POSIX http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (dirty, no error checking, buffer overflow may occur):

```
const char *sqlformat = 
            "INSERT INTO test_table(sensor_id, sensor_value) VALUES(%d, %f)";

char sql[200];
sprintf(sql, sensor_id, temp);
```

Now you have what you want in the `sql` buffer.

This is very basic C stuff, I suggest you to learn C.